# Incorrect marker(Mesh Resource) Visualization

Tags: ros, dae, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to visualize the following image as a marker(mesh resource) in the Rviz.

[image: image description]

But, in rviz it appears as:

[image: image description]

Can anyone please guide me on how can make my marker similar to the image above? Why am I losing all the details and RGB values in my marker?  The houses on the left (appearing in the picture) cannot be seen in the marker at all.

I did set the mesh_use_embedded_materials flag to true and all the r,g,b, values are set to zero. Also, I used online tools to convert my png image into .dae file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388352/incorrect-marker(mesh-resource)-visualization/) by [misty](https://answers.ros.org/users/58853/misty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-10-10**:
Have you tried setting r, g, b, and a to non-zero?
The Marker page says that setting r, g, b, and a to non-zero will add color.

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D

**Comment by [misty](https://answers.ros.org/users/58853/misty/) on 2021-10-11**:
I tried. That doesn't help.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-10-11**:
How about displaying the dae with a tool other than rviz?
This will help you to distinguish whether it is a defect in the dae file (problem in converting from png) or a problem on the rviz side.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-14**:
Pls take a look at this question: #q322457

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-14**:
Specifically at this repo: https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_textured_quads/tree/image_topic looks that allows you to do what you are looking for

**Comment by [misty](https://answers.ros.org/users/58853/misty/) on 2021-10-15**:
@osilva, thank you so much. The repository worked for me.
If it's possible for you, please put your comment as an answer so that I may accept it and close the issue.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-15**:
Glad it helped. I’ll add as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is Rviz plugin called [Rviz Texture Quads](https://github.com/MohitShridhar/rviz_textured_quads) that allows you to display textured images (realtime or static sensor_msgs/Image topics) as a marker in 3D space. In addition there is a cool demo by: https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_textured_quads/tree/image_topic that shows how to use it.

As mentioned in my comments, I found this info from prior question #q322457 so I hate to take any credit.

However, I'd like to add more info to this answer. The message is structured as follows:

```
sensor_msgs/Image   image           # texture 
geometry_msgs/Pose  pose            # 6DOF pose of the center of the quad to be displayed
float32             width           # physical width of the quad in Rviz unit (usually meters) 
float32             height          # physical height of the quad in Rviz unit (usually meters) 
string              caption         # [OPTIONAL] text description to appear below the quad
float32             border_size     # [OPTIONAL] size of the quad border
float32[]           border_color    # [OPTIONAL] (r,g,b,a) color value of the quad border (Size = 4)
```

And please review  the [source code](https://github.com/MohitShridhar/rviz_textured_quads/blob/master/src/mesh_display_custom.cpp) to understand how this is achieved in case someone else may want to apply similar concept but for different application, such as AR.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [misty](https://answers.ros.org/users/58853/misty/) on 2021-10-15**:
Best. Thanks a lot.